how to generate model constraint in cpmpy from a list?
I have a list of filters that I need to apply to my model as OR so they cannot be added separately to the model. I'm looking for syntax to do it. Is there a way to extend a constraint added to the model and add the OR options in a loop?
or some other cpmpy magic that can do that?
I'm trying to write a generator of the constraints to simplify the process. I have a pile of numpy arrays with the boolean values with "masks" to apply to the problem. I might end up with hundreds of them
p = cp.intvar(-1, 1, shape=(6, 6), name="test")
m = cp.Model()
m += (p != 0)

#applying one mask is trivial:
m += (abs(sum(puzzle[mask_array])) == 3)

# but I need to do it for many

# this is what I want in the end:
foo = some_list_of_numpy_arays
m += (abs(sum(p[foo[0]])) == 3) | (abs(sum(p[foo[1]])) == 3) | (abs(sum(p[foo[2]])) == 3)

# but in a loop as I do not know the number of elements in the list
for foo in some_iterator:
   # and I'm stuck with syntax here?
   m += (abs(sum(puzzle[foo[0]])) == 3) 

I could make strings and run eval but this seems way too hacky for this high level problem.
